# How does each platform display their own versions of emojis?

Tags: html, image, unicode, ascii, emoji

If you take a bit of text that contains emojis from whatsapp web, and paste it into facebook messenger, you'll get different versions on each platform. How does each platform use their own images as placeholders for emojis? Please note that the emoji code is preserved when copy-pasted. So a melon on one platform will still be a melon on the other platform.

I'm not even sure this is a programming question, if not I'd be very grateful if you could point me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Emoji are represented as unicode characters that individual platforms and apps can interpret as they see fit. While most modern platforms will automatically translate the unicode character into the appropriate image, some apps will override this behavior and replace the platform-standard unicode character with their own image.

```
text.replace("{unicodeEmojiString}", "{eitherAMarkerOrImageSpecificToMyApp}"
```